# How to add EventHandler to ContextMenu subitems in C#

Tags: c#, telerik, contextmenu

I've added some items and sub items to my `Telerik RadContextMenu`. I've successfully added `EventHandler` to the main items.

```
ctmTreeNode.Items["ctmTreeNodeNew"].Click += 
                           new EventHandler(ctmTreeNodeNew_Click);
ctmTreeNode.Items["ctmTreeNodeDelete"].Click += 
                           new EventHandler(ctmTreeNodeDelete_Click);
```

But I don't know how to do the same thing to my sub items. I tried the following but it doesn't work

```
ctmTreeNode.Items["ctmTreeNodeItem"].Items["ctmTreeNodeSubItem1"].Click +=
                           new EventHandler(ctmTreeNodeSubItem1_Click);
```

And if I do this

```
ctmTreeNode.Items["ctmTreeNodeSubItem1"].Click += 
                           new EventHandler(ctmTreeNodeSubItem1_Click);
```

I'll get null reference error

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: And how about'ctmTreeNodeSubItem1.Click += ctmTreeNodeSubItem1_Click;', does that work?

Comment: @Sjips Silly me! Haven't tried the obvious solution! Thank you!